# writing json string to firestore in c#

Tags: c#, json, google-cloud-firestore

I have a json string:

```
var jsonstr = "{ 'property1: 'myvalue','property2':2 }";
JObject json2 = JObject.Parse(jsonstr);
```

and want to write to firestore but the values are empty arrays instead of the values.

```
var task = collection.Document("test2").SetAsync(json2);
```

Comment: Maybe if you deserialize to `Dictionary<string, object` you can have the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NewtonSoft JSON : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json

You're going to want to Serialize your object.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
var text = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(configuration, settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

The json is missing a closing `'` character on `property1`.  Technically, you should be using double quotes instead of single on JSON.

`var jsonstr = "{ 'property1': 'myvalue','property2':2 }";`